# Handling FCM data messages if user clears notifications and app is in background android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

Title basically says it all. I have an app that uses FCM. I can receive the data message just fine if the app is in the foreground, or if the app is in the background and the user clicks the notification. However, what about the case where the user accidentally clears the notification? Or what about the case when the user opens the app not through the notification, but from a shortcut icon on your screen? In my case, I can't access the data message in both scenarios. In addition, what if the app is not currently running, how would the receiving side get the data message? I've looked around for answers, but there wasn't much in regards to my first question. The second question seems to be due to "white listed" apps only having permission to do something like that, I believe. How would I safely circumvent this?

UPDATE:
Code from index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

//Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
//https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database
.ref("shareWorkout/{senderToReceiver}/{workoutName}")
.onWrite(event => {
 var request = event.data.val();

 var payload = {
    //notification:{
     //   title: "Workout received",
     //   body: request.id.concat(' sent you a workout')
     //},
     data:{
         senderId: request.id,
         workoutName: request.workoutName
         //workout: request.workout
     }
 };

 admin.messaging().sendToDevice(request.token, payload)

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way is you need to do change it server side just need to remove notification class from notification payload and just add data key and put all your data in your data,

Remember don't put notification key, what this will do, you receive notification data always in the onMessageReceived method of your FCM class which extends FirebaseMessagingService, So now you can store your notification where you want means in local DB or file, and also you can access it later. (always means when you are accessing your app or not)

Comment: Isn't onMessageReceived only called when the app is in the foreground though?

Comment: If you implement what I say in your serverside you will get data every time in your onMessageRecive method.

Comment: How would I display a notification to the user informing them that they received something if the app is in the background/closed without the notification class then?

Comment: It doesn't matter your app is open, closed or in background, you can display notification by Using NotificationClass when to receive message in onMessageReceive method

Comment: onMessageReceived is never called when application is in background. I have updated my post with code from my index.js that is used for the cloud functions

Comment: Seems to work now. Added return to the last line of code. Thanks